# Merging async callback results in a single response with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have to read data from several mdb files in a nodejs/express application.
I am able do it with one file and send back the response:

```
var ADODB = require('node-adodb');

app.get('/data', function (req, res) {
  db = "mydb.mdb"
  var connection = ADODB.open('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=' + db);
  var query = 'SELECT * FROM [MyTable]';
  connection
    .query(query)
    .on('done', function (data) {
        r = JSON.stringify(data, null, '  ');
        res.end(JSON.stringify(r, null, '  '));
    })
    .on('fail', function (data) {
        res.end(JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
    });
})
```

Now I have to do it with a list of db names.
How can I merge all the `.on('done')` callbacks in a single `res.end(allData)` response if I do a `for loop` on the db names?

Answer (score 0):

use Promise.all(array) where the argument is a list of async Promises. The result will be a list of all the responses, in the same order as the promises in the array.

```
app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
  .. //Set up the promises
  var promise1 = connecetion.query(string);
  var promise2 = connecetion.query(string);

  Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(result) {
    res.send(result);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: I tested but maybe I am missing something. I have this result: `[
  {
    "domain": null,
    "_events": {},
    "params": {
      "connection": "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=A.mdb",
      "sql": "SELECT * FROM [SessionData]"
    }
  },
  {
    "domain": null,
    "_events": {},
    "params": {
      "connection": "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=B.mdb",
      "sql": "SELECT * FROM [SessionData]"
    }
  }
]`

Comment: never used ADODB and the docs seems to be asian. Cant read it. https://github.com/nuintun/node-adodb But you might want to try to use bleubird to promisify the callbacks..

Comment: this is an excellent post about how Promises work https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises

Comment: I am looking in his code [adodb.js](https://github.com/nuintun/node-adodb/blob/master/lib/adodb/adodb.js) to copy the `query: function(params)` but I am stuck with `new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Connection')`. How he managed to use it?

Comment: He uses `spawn` to run a js script with the `ADODB` ActiveX object.I changed the code in `proxy.js` to use a `spawnSync` and now I have a sync reading.